# Angular4 ngAfterViewChecked invoked multiple times when using setTimeout

Tags: angular

I have a service that I want to call once a view has been fully rendered. I did some digging around and found the Angular lifecycle. It seemed that the best method for me to use was `AfterViewChecked`, so I updated my **AppComponent** and added:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";

import { ResultsService } from "./shared/results.service";
import { HeightService } from "./shared/height.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'bzRoot',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _resultsService: ResultsService,
    private _heightService: HeightService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => this._resultsService.elq = params['elq']);
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}
```

When I run my application, I can see that the console has 25 instances of "hi" in it. I have no idea why it is so many, but that isn't the issue.
My method is calling a service I created which uses `postMessage` to send a message to the parent window. It looks like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeightService {

  constructor() { }

  public resize() {
    console.log('resizing');

    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( 
      body.scrollHeight, 
      body.offsetHeight, 
      body.clientHeight, 
      html.offsetHeight
    );

    setTimeout(function () {
      parent.postMessage(height, '*');
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

And my `ngAfterViewChecked` method now looks like this:

```js
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this._heightService.resize();
}
```

If I comment out the `setTimeout` line, it goes back down to 25 invocations.
Does anyone know why and how I can stop it from happening?

Comment: are you hooking into the resize event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) says  :

> ngAfterViewChecked()
>   Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.
>   Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().
>   A component-only hook.

You are looking for ngAfterViewInit() hooks

EDIT: It seems that angular hooks are not the solution to your needs, you should then save the last height value sent and trigger resize only if the value changed

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeightService {

  lastHeightPosted = null;
  constructor() { }

  public resize() {
    console.log('resizing');

    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( 
      body.scrollHeight, 
      body.offsetHeight, 
      body.clientHeight, 
      html.offsetHeight
    );

    if ( lastHeightPosted !== height) {
        parent.postMessage(height, '*');
        lastHeightPosted = height;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
     this._heightService.resize();
  }
}
```

Comment: AfterViewInit won't work though, I need all content to have loaded, not to be invoked when the view initiates